# vb.net manager.SendEmail Syntax

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Can someone tell me what the correct syntax should be here in VB.net?

```
    manager.SendEmail(user.Id, "Confirm your account", 
    "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=""" 
    & callbackUrl & """ here></a>")
```

is returning:

```
    Please confirm your account by clicking <a 
    href="http://myIPAddress.xxx.xxx/Account/Confirm? 
    code=iuN8rC9bHCJYMTjd1wshmhTT%2bxh5%2fVrVblablalbla....." here></a>
```

It shouldn't include the tags, and I think it may be a malformed URL that is causing issues in sending the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with VB.NET. But one thing is clear.

```
manager.SendEmail(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=""" & callbackUrl & """ here></a>")
```

The here part needs to be inside the element tags, not inside the angle brackets. Should be:

```
manager.SendEmail(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=""" & callbackUrl & """>here</a>")
```

There may be other syntax problems with VB.NET I'm not familiar with, but I know for sure you need to make the above change.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, but it still doesn't look right. I made the suggested change, and am getting: `Please confirm your account by clicking <a href="MyIp.xxx.xxx/Account/Confirm?code=2Fw0%2fw7Tvv4......">; here</a>`

Comment: @user2796515 Doublecheck the value of your `callbackUrl`.